# Angular (version 8) - Subscribe not firing

Tags: angular, observable, subject

I'm trying to establish communication between components by using observables and [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject).

This is my service.

**CommonService**

```
  private style = new Subject<string>();

  getStyle(): Observable<any> {
    return this.style.asObservable();
  }

  updateStyleArray(styleToApply) {
    this.style.next(styleToApply);
  }
```

The component in which i try to subscribe with the getStyle() method, has the following code inside the constructor.

**BottomBar**

```
    this.commonService.getStyle().subscribe(style => {
      console.log('I am firing in order not to be fired!!!');
    });
```

The component in which i call the *next()* method has the following code.

**Sidebar**

```
 this.commonService.updateStyleArray('This is the name of a style');
```

I have simplified the code to a bare minimum but it still doesn't fire the *subcribe()* function.

----> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7kidgc)

**Solution and NOTE**

The above technique works like a charm in order to establish communication between components. The error was caused because
app-bottom-bar was implemented with an `ngIf*` and the constructor was not called*, therefore the subscribe function was not called.

*`<app-bottom-bar *ngIf="isBottomBarVisible"></app-bottom-bar>` .

Comment: How are you registering your services? As component providers, module providers or `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`?

Comment: @KurtHamilton 

--->
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

Comment: Can you recreate in stackblitz?

Comment: StackBlitz added

Comment: Where should `bottom-bar` be rendered? I don't see it in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BottomBarComponent` constructor is not called. Hence you haven't actually subscribed.

**Fix** - stick this in `app.component.html`

```
<app-bottom-bar></app-bottom-bar>
```

Comment: good catch. Actually in th rel app i have it, ..but inside an ngIf*..

Comment: That makes the stackblitz run, so its very close to the solution. On the other hand
I put a bookmark and when i reload the page it shows that the constructor is called.
I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @yeaaaahhhh..hamfhamf is this after you've added `<app-bottom-bar></app-bottom-bar>` somewhere? Are you doing anything fancy with  `BottomBarComponent` other than render

Answer (score 0):

Can you change

```
private style = new BehaviorSubject <string>();
```

It could happen that bottombar is render before the sidebar hence causing the subscription to be lost. BehaviorSubject will make the last subscription available to all the component.

Thanks

Comment: I think the BehaviourSubject needs to be initiated with a value. I tried that already

Answer (score 0):

`Subject` will not replay old values for new subscribers. Therefore, if you called `updateStyleArray()` before your subscription happens, it will not fire until a new call to `updateStyleArray()` will be made.

To solve this you could replace your `Subject` with a [ReplaySubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) and set the buffer size to 1:

```
  private style = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
```

Now your style observable will buffer the last value and also emit this value if you subscribe after `style.next()` was called.

Comment: The updateStyleArray() is called when a button is clicked and the subscription is inside the constructor.